# How do I access a variable in sphinx conf.py from my .rst file?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm brand new to Sphinx and reStructuredText.

Inside my Sphinx `conf.py` I defined:

```
version = '0.0.2'
```

Inside of `tutorial.rst` I want access the `version` variable and display `0.0.2` in my html file. I tried:

```
version

|version|

:version:

.. |version|

.. :version:
```

I succeeded in testing the contents of the version.

```
.. ifconfig:: version == '0.0.2'

    This prints!
```

This was encouraging, but not what I want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want this to be available everywhere, you can do something like this:

**conf.py**

```
rst_epilog = """
.. |ProjectVersion| replace:: Foo Project, version {versionnum}
""".format(
versionnum = version,
)
```

**file.rst**

```
As one may see, we have made significant strides in |ProjectVersion| 
and hope that you enjoy the product!
```

The *rst_epilog* list makes items within it globally-available to compiled .rst files. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_epilog

Comment: Since the `rst_epilog` is evaluated when the conf.py file is read, overriden config values with `-D` are not taken into account this way.

Comment: using `|ProjectVersion|` inside `.. code-block` directive doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You mention "The rst_epilog list", but it is not a (python) list right?

Comment: @viveksinghggits: Inside a `.. code-block`, there is no parsing for rST inline elements. You may consider usind [parsed-literal](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#parsed-literal) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party. If you have a bunch of variables inside `conf.py` that you want to use in your rst files you can use the following solution (it is based on Chris answer).
Let suppose in the `conf.py` there are declarations like:

```
version = "1.0.0"
copyright = "Mario, 2010"
project = "foobar"
```

open `conf.py` and append at the end of the file the following:

```
variables_to_export = [
    "project",
    "copyright",
    "version",
]
frozen_locals = dict(locals())
rst_epilog = '\n'.join(map(lambda x: f".. |{x}| replace:: {frozen_locals[x]}", variables_to_export))
del frozen_locals
```

Now perform:

```
make html
```

and voilà.

BTW "project, copyright, versions" are just some test variables.