# Sphinx- Print in a rst file a custom string variable defined in conf.py

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

I am defining in conf.py a string variable `X` that I would like to print in a rst file. Here is what I did :

In conf.py:

```
X = "MY CUSTOM STRING"
```

In the rst file:

```
Using |X|
```

But the html shows:

[image]

instead of showing the content of `MY CUSTOM STRING` as defined in conf.py

**How can I make html show the content of X instead of the letter X ?**

The idea is to have X behave just like the variable `release` that is by default written in conf.py. When we do `|release|` in a rst file and in conf.py we have `release = "0.0.1"`, then the html show 0.0.1 and not |release| :

[image]

Comment: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_epilog -- `rst_epilog = ".. |X| replace:: MY CUSTOM STRING"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access a variable in sphinx conf.py from my .rst file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006784/how-do-i-access-a-variable-in-sphinx-conf-py-from-my-rst-file)

Comment: unfortunately the links given do not answer the question, the usage of rst epilog makes the variable printed in every page of the documentation, I would like to print it in one page only

Comment: The "rst epilog" is prepended to every page of the documentation. If it contains a substitution *definition*, nothing is printed but you are free to use the substitution in every document.